# How to get entire request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I would like to get the entire request (header and body just as they appear when they arrive at the application) in Node.js. I'm able to get it by reading directly from the socket on connection (example below), but I haven't found a way to associate it with a particular request object as it's processed by the server.

```
...
var server = http.createServer(app).listen();
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
});

...

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  //get the data that would be output from the above snippet in this context
  //do something with it
});
```

This is just one example to illustrate what I'm looking for, I'm open to any method to achieve this other than attempting to reconstruct the request from information provided in the request object.

Comment: @Thomas I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: I've edited my question to include additional clarity based on the deleted answer from Quentin (it wasn't me who downvoted you Quentin, sorry).

Comment: Why specifically do you need it in that form?

Comment: @robertklep For the moment it's just for displaying to the client. There are a few other ideas in the works if it can be done in Node.